# Self Sizing UITableViewCell not working for Right Detail Cells

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I am trying to use the new (since iOS8) feature for self-sizing UITableViewCells. Unfortunately it does not work right when using a *Right Detail* Cell.

**My Setup**

I am using a UITableViewController. Therefore a UITableViewCell is already configured. I set the UITableViewCell style to "Right Detail". Then I set the numberOfLines property of the detailTextLabel to 0 in order to grow when I provide a bunch of text.

**Problem**

The result looks like this:
[image: Right Detail Cell]

When I am changing the UITableViewCell to some other style like "Left Detail" it works:
[image: Left Detail Cell]

It also works if I use a custom UITableViewCell subclass which I am using now but I am still wondering why the Right-Detail style does not work.

**Question**

Why is the self sizing UITableViewCell not working when using a Right-Detail cell style ?

Also does anybody have a fix for this ?

Comment: What are your constraints on the right cells ? Check the same thing out with the lef-detail but having a longer text so it also occupies 3 lines

Comment: The constraints are set automatically as far as I know. This is because Right Detail and Left Detail Cells are predefined UITableViewCell Styles.

Comment: Just guessing, but worth a try: set the constrainsts manually with the hight <= xxx, where xxx = the maximum hight you want to allow (I often use 63 = 3 lines of 21 high)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem.

Eventually I gave up on the "Right Detail" in favor of my own custom one:

1. I created my own simple class that inherited from the UITableViewCell:

   ```
   class TransactionCell: UITableViewCell
   {

   }
   ```
2. I set my prototype cell use that custom class by setting the "Style" field to "Custom" on the "Table View Cell" Menu and by adding "TransactionCell" to the "Class" field of the "Custom Class" menu. These menus are available when you select the prototype cell in the storyboard.
   [image][image]
3. I added two labels to my prototype cell and connected them to my custom class by right click dragging from my labels to my class (Oddly, I had to clean my build before it would let me do this):

   ```
   class TransactionCell: UITableViewCell{

       @IBOutlet weak var detailsLabel: UILabel!

       @IBOutlet weak var amountLabel: UILabel!

   }
   ```
4. I added new constraints to my labels, taking advantage of swift's autolayout features (You will need to set these to match your own requirements; see a tutorial on autolayout if you are stuck)

[image: How to add new constraints: click on the thing to add constraints to then click on this symbol]

5. ...and set the "Lines" and "Line Breaks" fields in the respective "Label" menus so that the spacing between labels would be even and so that my details label could flex to multiple lines.
   [image]

It worked for me, allowing me to have the flexibility of different amounts of multiple lines in a UITableView in swift per cell, while formatting the word wrapping so that it looked nice and even, like I would have expected the "Right Detail" to do automatically.

Please mark as the answer if this was what you were looking for :)